# Classic ASP Read CSV information inside an XML file

Tags: xml, dom, csv, asp-classic

I have a script that reads an XML file using the DOM without problem. If I check the result, I get the CSV information contained in the node in question. However, I have a problem to read that information. I have a variable that contains it as a text/string, but I do not know how to split that text according to the new line in order to separate each CSV informations. As my search on the Web leads to a great lack of result, I allow me to ask this question to the community.

Note : I already try stuffs like :

```
myCsv = Replace(myCsv,vbCrLf,"<br>")
myCsv = Split(myCsv, "<br>")
```

or like : `myCsv = Split(myCsv, vbCrLf)`.

Thank you !
Regards,
Phil

Comment: Have you checked exactly what character(s) is used for the new line? It might not be vbCrLf. If it is not vbCrLf (ASCII 10+13) then it could be just vbCr (ASCII 13) or VbLf (ASCII 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML parser will reduce any CRLF sequence in XML to simply LF.  Hence you should be using this line:

```
myCsv = Split(myCsv, vbLf)
```